# Why won't re.groups() give me anything for my one correctly-matched group?

Tags: python, regex, object, match, capture-group

When I run this code:

```
print re.search(r'1', '1').groups()
```

I get a result of `()`. However, `.group(0)` gives me the match.

Shouldn't `groups()` give me something containing the match?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

groups is empty since you do not have any capturing groups - http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups. group(0) will always returns the whole text that was matched regardless of if it was captured in a group or not

Edited.

Comment: That's the `groups` field, not the method

Answer (score 26):

To the best of my knowledge, `.groups()` returns a tuple of *remembered groups*. I.e. those groups in the regular expression that are enclosed in parentheses. So if you were to write:

```
print re.search(r'(1)', '1').groups()
```

you would get

```
('1',)
```

as your response. In general, `.groups()` will return a tuple of all the groups of objects in the regular expression that are enclosed within parentheses.

Answer (score 5):

The reason for this is that you have no capturing groups (since you don't use `()` in the pattern).
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups

And `group(0)` returns the entire search result (even if it has no capturing groups at all):
http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group

Answer (score 5):

You have no groups in your regex, therefore you get an empty list (`()`) as result.

Try

```
re.search(r'(1)', '1').groups()
```

With the brackets you are creating a capturing group, the result that matches this part of the pattern, is stored in a group.

Then you get

```
('1',)
```

as result.