# Python's 'match' line in _sre.SRE_Match output? Can it show the full match?

Tags: python, regex, match

Using python 3:

```
In [275]: blah = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffg"

In [276]: pat = re.compile("([a-z]{2,9999})")

In [277]: data = re.search(pat,blah)

In [278]: data
Out[278]: <_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 125), match='fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff>
```

Is it possible for `match=''` to print out the whole string? i.e all the way to the final `'g'`?

Comment: The pattern only matches 99 characters, the rest is not part of the match.

Comment: Why do you limit it to `{2,99}` if you want a longer match?

Comment: thanks. I edited my posted. Even with 9999 I don't see the full end to the 'g'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible. That length is hard coded in the format string in the match object's `repr` method and is not designed to capture the full length of the matched string.

Except you compile your own build of CPython (or whatever Python flavour you're at) with the precision of the representation of the `match` object in [`match_repr`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/fbb490fd2f38bd817d99c20c05121ad0168a38ee/Modules/_sre.c#L2321) modified. Default precision is 50:

```c
result = PyUnicode_FromFormat(
        "<%s object; span=(%d, %d), match=%.50R>",
        Py_TYPE(self)->tp_name,
        self->mark[0], self->mark[1], group0);
```

As others have suggested, simply use the [`group`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.group) method of the match object to access the full matching string(s).

Comment: Thank you. No is the answer, then. I am unconcerned with group methods.

Answer (score 1):

With this one you don't constrain yourself with any upper limit of repetitions:

```
import re

blah = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffg"

r = re.compile(r'[a-z](.)\1{2,}') # no upper limit
try:
    re.search(r, blah).group()
except AttributeError:
    pass  # whatever you want to do when there is no match
```

Answer (score 0):

You are probably looking for the .group ...

```
import re
blah = "ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffg"
pat = re.compile("([a-z]{2,99})")
data = re.search(pat,blah)
if data:
    data.group(0) # returns 'fffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff'
else:
    pass # do something when the string was not found!
```

See:
https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/re.html#re.match.group

and

[Why won't re.groups() give me anything for my one correctly-matched group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7312020/why-wont-re-groups-give-me-anything-for-my-one-correctly-matched-group#7312049)

Comment: Thanks. But, no I am not.